# How to write a regex lookahead/lookbehind in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP (abc)(?=def)
```

and I got the error

```
Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

due to the '?' -> see [#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317183/1139-got-error-repetition-operator-operand-invalid-from-regexp#18317617)

Is there an equivalent in mysql that I don't see in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html ?

or maybe another mysql function that I don't know yet?

Comment: Ah, rats. I thought the duplicate target had an actual link to the official documentation explaining that those features don’t exist in mySQL. It links to the general Regex reference though, to which you also link. Sorry. Either way the bottom line seems to be that the features aren’t there

Comment: @Pekka웃 Can you repoen?

Comment: @Tim I’m not sure, I’ve never tried. Do you have an answer that differs from the one in the duplicate target?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, I have a workaround and I was 5 seconds from posting when you closed.

Comment: @Tim of course. Done.

Comment: MariaDB, a mySQL fork, seems to have this now https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/#positive-and-negative-look-ahead-and-look-behind-assertions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL `REGEXP` does not support lookaheads, but you can try to achieve the same logic using something like this:

```
WHERE column LIKE 'abc%' AND
      SUBSTRING(column, INSTR(column, 'abc') + 3, 3) <> 'def'
```

Comment: Close.  But fails to catch `"abcdef xyz abc"`.  But I guess this is an ambiguous case.  Does guillaume want this row or not?

Comment: wouw, I didn't expect that my question will be answered so quickly.
It took me some time to understand what you were trying to do here (didn't know the functions `SUBSTRING`, neither `INSTR`) and that's an interesting trick I couldn't possibly think about. Nevertheless I can't test it right now, I hope it will be used by someone else...

Comment: had to do something similar today and remembered the question I asked :)
well, it works ^^